# Highcharts - How to prevent long title with line break from overflowing subtitle

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart in three languages with data filled from a database. Some of the translated titles will break and fill two lines. Without any precaution this will overflow the subtitles:

```
title: {
    text: 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and even more',
    style: {
        width: '320px'
    }
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr'
},
```

See this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/puhtu/

Is there a way to dynamically move the subtitles if the main title breaks in two lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug so I've reported it to our devs https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1704

Answer (score 0):

Although a while ago, the following fixed it for me since this is still an issue:

```
            title: {
                text: "Hello very strange world where people tend to make long chart titles",
                style: {
                    fontSize: '1.9vmin',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: '#1381bc',
                    lineHeight: '15em' //This line did the trick
                },
                align: 'left',
                x: 30,
                y: 10
            },
```